# pool.request() is not a function

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sql-server-2008, node-mssql

```
enter code here

**my dbconnection.js**  

  const sql = require("mssql");
const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'abhi',
    server: 'ABHI\\MSSQLSERVER01', 
    database: 'online_video_streaming' 
};
const poolPromise =new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
    .connect()
     .then (pool =>{
        console.log("connected")
            return pool.request()
        }).catch(err => console.log("failed to connect", err));
console.log("connection", poolPromise)
  module.exports = {
                    poolPromise:poolPromise,
                    sql:sql
                };

**my users.js**
const {sql,poolPromise} = require('../../dbconnection');
router.post('/getcatlist', async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const pool = await poolPromise;
    const request = await pool.request();
  let userquery = 'SELECT  * FROM cat_1_level_1';
  let response = await request.query(userquery);
  res.send("200",response);
  console.log(response);
}catch (e){
  console.error(e)
}
});
```

**output:**
tedious deprecated The default value for `config.options.enableArithAbort` will change from `false` to `true` in the next major version of `tedious`. Set the value to `true` or `false` explicitly to silence this message. node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:61:23

connection Promise { pending }
connected
TypeError: pool.request is not a function
    at C:\Users\ABHILASH M\Desktop\nodejs\Online_video_streaming2\routes\portal\manage\user.js:430:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `pool.request()` in db.js.

Do this instead:

```
const poolPromise =new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
    .connect()
    .then (pool =>{
        console.log("connected")
        return pool
    })
    .catch(err => console.log("failed to connect", err));
```

Also, you started well with `const`, but then you started declaring things as mutable that never get mutated. Change those `let` statements to `const` and you'll keep on #winning. See [this article](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/shun-the-mutant/).

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help a brother out. Feel free to accept it as the solution :-)